# Python return jsonp for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, autocomplete, jsonp

I am using autocomplete of devbridge https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/.
I am trying to get json data inside the same server but in different ports. So I have problem with cross domain. I have tried and read many different approaches about this problem but I cannot manage to solve it. So I have a python function which returns this:

```
formatted_codes = {'query': query, 'suggestions':jsonData, 'data': jsonData}
data = json.dumps(formatted_codes)
return HttpResponse("callback(%s);"%data,mimetype="application/javascript")
```

and I am trying to use it in autocomplete as:

```
$(function(){
options = {
    serviceUrl:'http://linkname/apps/getSuggestions/start_auth?record_id=4dfcb2eb-1c71-4da1-8b3e-cbf4918a042;query=can;',

   // jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {


                    return { value: data.suggestions};

    },
      error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
};
a = $('#query').devbridgeAutocomplete(options);
```

});

But it is not working. It says that ReferenceError: callback is not defined
and in firebug I can see the result of python function which is :

```
callback({'query': 'can', 'suggestions': ['Cane', 'Canal', 'Candy', 'Canis', 'Canoe', 'Canada', 'Canary', 'Canola', 'Cantil', 'Decane', 'Toucan', 'Candida', 'Candiru', 'Candoia', 'Canidae', 'Cannula', 'Indican', 'Pelican', 'Scanner', 'Acanthis'], 'data': ['Cane', 'Canal', 'Candy', 'Canis', 'Canoe', 'Canada', 'Canary', 'Canola', 'Cantil', 'Decane', 'Toucan', 'Candida', 'Candiru', 'Candoia', 'Canidae', 'Cannula', 'Indican', 'Pelican', 'Scanner', 'Acanthis']});
```

I have also tried with jsonCallback: 'callback',  variable. I have also tried to return just text and not json. I don't know what to do. What should I return with python function in order to work with autocomplete? I believe that my problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the `HttpResponse` part of your Python script, in which you make a reference to `callback()`. I dont know if I fully understand this but wouldn't returning plain JSON be better for your purpose? So something like:

```
formatted_codes = {'query': query, 'suggestions':jsonData, 'data': jsonData}
return HttpResponse(formatted_codes, mimetype="application/json")
```

I think that should be sufficient, even without the `json.dumps` part, but I'm not entirely sure. So you could also return:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(formatted_codes), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: No because there is the cross domain problem. If you return json it is blocked because of security. So the only format capable of avoiding this solution is jsonp. But jsonp if I have understand correctly should be rapped in a script function like callbackFuncation({'query':q,'data':data... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution but requires access to the server. I used simple json format and I resolved the cross-domain problem by changing settings in Apache2.
In /etc/apache2/sites-available/default I added inside < VirtualHost *:8000 > this lines:

```
 Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
 Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Also inside

```
 <Directory /web/indivo_server>
 Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
 Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
 </Directory>
```

I also enabled mod_headers

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

uncomment line in http.conf or apache2.conf:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

and restart apache2:

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it helps.